# Make facebook like button width dynamic

Tags: html, css, facebook

I have facebook like and share iframe buttons side by side. The like button also has a counter. The problem is when the like button width increases (due to counter reaching mutliple digits or facebook user having a local where "like" is a longer word) then the like button will be cut off. Is it possible to somehow make like button width dynamic?

Here is the code:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fforums.asdf.com%2Fviewtopic.php%3Ff%3D5%26t%3D2523%26start%3D80&width=60&layout=button_count&action=like&size=small&show_faces=false&share=false&height=21&appId" width="60" height="20" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fforums.asdf.com%2Fviewtopic.php%3Ff%3D5%26t%3D2523%26start%3D80&layout=button_count&size=small&mobile_iframe=false&width=68&height=20&appId" width="68" height="20" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

And here is an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/vd8ybhee/1/

Comment: my understanding of iframes is that if you don't own the origin src where the iframe comes from then you're stuck with whatever styles they impose on you.

Comment: This looks like an older version of the like button, no? Maybe update to the latest version?

Comment: Thats the code that facebook gave me when i generated the like button. How can i get a newer version?

Comment: Yeah you shouldn't be using the iframe, they have a non-blocking js version. I put the demo code here https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/YVBqrz doesn't work on codepen but should work on a normal non-iframe-sandboxed site.

Comment: @user1985273 where and when did you generate that [**Like Button**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button)?

Comment: @hungerstar - yes thats the same link where i generated it from and i generated it when asking this question. so it cant be very old.

Comment: @MichaelCoker I tried the JS buttons but had problem with adding them dynamically to the page so i resorted to iframe buttons. maybe i should look into js version again.